# Install boto3 from a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using docker. In one of my container I want to use boto3 so for that I used this command from inside the container

```
RUN apt-get install boto3
```

but it showed me like

```
bash: RUN: command not found
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get install boto3` but it also showed me error like

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

So can someone tell me how to install a package in a docker container?

**Update**

When I make `docker ps -a`

I get this

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND      CREATED  STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
                                       distracted_rubin
6a8b04e81122        odoo:11.0           "/entrypoint.sh odoo"    6 weeks ago         Up 4 hours                8071/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18069->8069/tcp   odoo
```

As you can see mu container id is `6a8b04e81122` I used this command to go inside container

```
docker exec -it 6a8b04e81122 /bin/bash
```

Comment: whats image did you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**odoo** image by [default](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/c6b79809f0772c419f681889b810ae4aaff8ec37/11.0/Dockerfile#L75) uses a user called **odoo**. This user doesn't have enough privilege to install a package.

So you have to create a container with different user (i.e) root.

> docker run -it --user root odoo:11 bash

Now you created a container with **root** user context.

You can install **boto3** by issuing below command.

```
apt update 
For python 2.x: apt install python-boto3 
For python 3.x: apt install python3-boto3
```

Finally, commit the container to persist the changes.

**Update:**

You can also open the existing container with a different user by issuing the below command.

`docker exec -it --user root <container-id> bash`

Comment: Remember that anything you do with `docker exec` will get lost as soon as the container exits.